# Problems opening nested Bootstrap accordion group using jQuery

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am using Bootstrap and jQuery. I have an accordion group and one of the groups also has an inner/nested accordion group. The html for this is ( and is also here in a [js fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/PugwashXP/xge5uc1v/19/)):

```
<h3>Accordion test</h3>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#p-counts-2">Open counts 2</button>
<div class="accordion" id="p-lists">
    <div class="accordion-group">
        <div class="accordion-heading"> <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#p-lists" href="#p-lists-1">
                    <h5>Group 1</h5>
            </a>

        </div>
        <div id="p-lists-1" class="accordion-body collapse">
            <div class="accordion-inner">Body p1</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="accordion-group">
        <div class="accordion-heading"> <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#p-lists" href="#p-lists-2">
                    <h5>Group 2</h5>
            </a>

        </div>
        <div id="p-lists-2" class="accordion-body collapse">
            <div class="accordion-inner">
                 <h4>Inner accordion</h4>

                <!-- Start of inner -->
                <div class="accordion" id="p-counts">
                    <div class="accordion-group">
                        <div class="accordion-heading"> <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#p-counts" href="#p-counts-1">
                    <h5>Counts 1</h5>
            </a>

                        </div>
                        <div id="p-counts-1" class="accordion-body collapse">
                            <div class="accordion-inner">Counts p1</div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="accordion-group">
                        <div class="accordion-heading"> <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#p-counts" href="#p-counts-2">
                    <h5>Counts 2</h5>
            </a>

                        </div>
                        <div id="p-counts-2" class="accordion-body collapse">
                            <div class="accordion-inner">Counts p2</div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!-- end of inner -->
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="accordion-group">
        <div class="accordion-heading"> <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#p-lists" href="#p-lists-3">
                    <h5>Group 3</h5>
            </a>

        </div>
        <div id="p-lists-3" class="accordion-body collapse">
            <div class="accordion-inner">Body p3</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I have two interactions that I am struggling to create:

1. When Groups 1 or 3 is opened, *and* Group 2 is open with one of the inner groups open, Group 2 closes correctly but the inner groups remain open when I reopen group 2; I want them to close at the same time group 2 closes - how do I do this?
2. I want to open one of the inner groups using an external link - how do I do this?

I have tried various JQuery and JavaScript functions but end up with very smelly code and incomplete functionality

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A colleague at work came up with the necessary jQuery/Javascript response which is posted [here](https://jsfiddle.net/PugwashXP/xge5uc1v/38/)

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    // Collapse inner groups:
    $('#p-lists').on('hide', function(e){
        // Force a collapse (.hide() doesn't seem to work properly here but is unnecessary anyway):
        $(e.target).find('.accordion-body')
        .removeClass('in')
        .attr('style', '');
    });

    // Make sure parent groups are also opened:
    $('#p-lists').on('show', function(e){

        var $parent = $(e.target).parents('.accordion-body');
        // Collapse all siblings:
        $parent.parents('.accordion-group')
        .prevAll('.accordion-group').find('.accordion-body').collapse('hide')
        .nextAll('.accordion-group').find('.accordion-body').collapse('hide');
        // Then open THIS parent:
        $parent.collapse('show');
    });
});
```