# Bootstrap accordion: collapse all except parent

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have multiples accordions in the same page. Some of them inside another accordion.

When one panel is clicked, I need to close all open panels. This is simple:

```
$('.panel-group').on('show.bs.collapse', function (event) {
    $('.collapse.in').collapse('hide');
});
```

But I need to check if the panel is not parent of the clicked panel. How can I do this?

An example of my issue: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/RRkBJw?editors=1010

Comment: Can you show your HTML?

Comment: @makshh This is one of many accordions with another accordion inside http://pastebin.com/BtKNxYGf

Comment: "But I need to check if the panel is not parent of the clicked panel." Can you explain it in more detail? Sorry, I don't get it.

Comment: @makshh I created an example on CodePen. How can I open Sub item 2 without close Main title?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar problem with nested accordions. The following answer might help. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31636219/problems-opening-nested-bootstrap-accordion-group-using-jquery) answer/question.

Answer (score 1):

Found a solution:

```
$('.panel-group').on('show.bs.collapse', function (event) {
    var parent = $(event.target).parents('.collapse.in');
    $('.collapse.in').not(parent).collapse('hide');
});
```